# Automatically posting in Google+ (users already authenticated with OAuth)

Tags: google-plus, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to automatically add a Post in Google+, in behalf of a user that already give my system App permission using OAuth.

I've been checking https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client and https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/ but not sure if "Add a Post" is allowed because in case of "Comments" objects I only see GET a list or item.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Depending on what you mean by 'automatically' that may violate Google Policy. A user must explicitly initiate all posts with the option to edit, they can't be done automatically https://developers.google.com/+/web/policies#posts_to_stream_and_notifications

Comment: Thanks, means that user can scheduled a Post to be "added" in its Google+ later through my system. Thanks for the link!

Comment: But, if user initialize the action and then I make him aware of what's going to be published, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Yea it sounds like what you're trying to do is within the limits of the Policy I linked. But I couldn't find anything that would allow you to submit a post. The closest I could find was adding a Share which doesn't sound like what you're doing. The API looks to be primarily read only with few exceptions. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Google+ basically does not support automated posting. Your best bet is to check out the [share feature](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/).